# about search using Lucene?

Tags: solr, lucene, elasticsearch

I am using Lucene based search engine.

For example, I have a field like "name": "blue sky"

I can search use blue or sky, but not blu. I think blu is part of blue, why I cannot search the blu?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use wildcard (`blu*`) or fuzzy searches (`blu~`). More information available [here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1).

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can define a special mapping to cover that need.
For example, in elasticsearch, you can define a [edgeNgram](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/edgengram-tokenizer.html) analyzer for the field.

WildcardQueries searches are slower than termQueries. You can use also [PrefixQuery](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/prefix-query.html).